# How to Find record by ObjectID's property in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have 2 models like Orders and Customers.

```
const orders = mongoose.Schema({
      customer_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId      
      required: true,
      ref: 'Customer',
    },
    OrderNo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    })

const customers = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    })
```

I want to filter **orders based on customer's name** as per below.

```
let query = {
        'customer_id.name': { $regex: '.*AMAZON.*' },
      }

await Orders.find(query)
```

but its not working properly. I'm new to mongodb. Can anyone share feasible solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to `populate` and filter the resulting fields:

```
await Orders.find({})
  .populate({ path: 'customer_id', match: { name: { $regex: '.*AMAZON.*' } } })
  .exec();
```